# Volume and stationary values

Tags: calculus

[image]

I don't understand how to do any of the above questions, would someone be able to give me some tips on what functions i'm supposed to use?

Comment: Rolled back. If you're trying to cover your tracks, it won't work.

Comment: funny, i've been putting my answers up on each question, keep it up  all means but i was under the impression it was considerate to remove questions i don't need anymore

Comment: Editing the question to remove the body doesn't remove it, and it eliminates any and all context for the answers that other people took time to write. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not complete! I will work using
$$
V=4x^3-66x^2+216x
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dV}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(4x^3-66x^2+216x)=12x^2-132x+216
$$
Stationary point can be obtained by setting $\frac{dV}{dx}=0$.
\begin{align}
12x^2-132x+216&=0\\
12(x^2-11x+18)&=0\\
x^2-11x+18&=0
\end{align}
It only has one value, namely $x=2$ because:
\begin{align}
x^2-11x+18&=0\\
(x-9)(x-2)&=0\\
x=9\quad&;\quad x=2
\end{align}
$V(x) < 0$ for $x=9$ (impossible for physical quantity).
$$
\frac{d^2V}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(12x^2-132x+216)=24x-132
$$
$\cfrac{d^2V}{dx^2}=-84$ for $x=2$. Because $\cfrac{d^2V}{dx^2}<0$, then the stationary value is a maximum.

Comment: could and should i use a quadratic to show working? $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\ }}{2a}$$ for getting 2 and 9 i mean :)

Comment: @John Of course you could use that formula. You also could use complete square